# Functional language with design by contract feature

Tags: functional-programming, jvm, clr, design-by-contract

I am looking for a functional language with good design by contract feature (preferably first class, but i good library would also do).The best i could find so far is Racket http://racket-lang.org/, but i looking for something on either the JVM or the CLR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at Clojure -- is a recent dialect of the Lisp programming language. It is a functional general-purpose language. Its focus on programming with immutable values and explicit progression-of-time constructs are intended to facilitate the development of more robust programs, particularly multithreaded ones.

Also Clojure can work at .Net.

http://clojure.org/

Comment: I checked Clojure before, while it has some very nice features indeed ,i fail to see any real design by contract orientation in the language